# Replace App Bar with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I'm new to Android Studio, and I've been trying to replace the default `AppBar` with a customized Toolbar. I am following [developer.android.com/training/appbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) tutorial, and I've done everything, correctly (I think).

The problem is that when I add my `toolbar` it doesn't replace the default one, but instead it's placed just below. I've follow every step of the tutorial, but it's still like that.

Comment: Now go and read this article (You will find the section How to make Toolbar work as ActionBar) https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html. I will recommend you reading the difference between Toolbar And ActionBar. Makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove your default appbar.

Put it on your **style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In **menifests.xml** do coding like this :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ReceiveSingleScanActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
         />
```

As your Comment:

> I've solved the problem, but now that the bar is shown, it doesn't
>   show the app title nor the menu

your menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
      android:title="Bookmark" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
      android:title="Save" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="Search" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
      android:title="Share" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
      android:title="Delete" />  

<item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
      android:title="Preferences" />
```

Activity code should be like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_inventory_result);
    setToolbar();
    views();
    init();
}


    //for initialize and set Title of toolbar
    private void setToolbar() {
        toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarAdjust);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Count Inventory");
    }
```

for creating menu :

```
 // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
 * Identify single menu item by it's id
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_bookmark:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_save:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_search:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_share:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_delete:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_preferences:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved the problem, but now that the bar is shown, it doesn't show the app title nor the menu

Answer (score 0):

Appending answers to your newer questions as per your comment in the answer of @Abhishek kumar:

> I've solved the problem, but now that the bar is shown, it doesn't show the app title nor the menu

To show the app title on your customized toolbar, there are 2 ways to achieve it:

*1st method:* In **AndroidManifest.xml** you could add the value for **android:label**:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".ReceiveSingleScanActivity"
     android:label="ReceiveSingleScanActivity" 
     <!-- (or any string from strings.xml could be passed here as well) -->
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

*2nd method:* You can also set app title in your activity class using the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ReceiveSingleScanActivity");
```

Using the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) to show the menu on your custom action bar you need to:

Firstly, Create a menu xml (named menu.xml) file as described in the documentation above.

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>
```

Then override ***onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)*** method in your activity to inflate the menu in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu (menu.xml); this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Finally override ***onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)*** method in your activity as well to add action to the buttons in your menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favorite:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct Answer @DharaBhavsar